# How to import class from a referenced library imported form .jar in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar

I try to use some classes from org.apache.http.client.methods.

I downloaded the .jar file it is in, uploaded it in the lib folder in the project, added that jar to the build path, but I still cannot import these classes in my .java file in the src file. How can I make that happen?

Comment: right-click on the project -> go to properties, then click on build path, then on Library tab, check if jar is there

Comment: Open the jar file with a zip tool of your choice, then check if it contains e.g. file `org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.class`. If not, then you got the wrong jar file.

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file in the default package, delete it (or learn about [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) and add the required `requires` statement).